# matching timezone to a specifc time range in php

Tags: php, timezone

I'm trying to figure out a way in php to give a time range (say 1pm-1:59pm) and return a timezone/location where that is the current time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate how many hours that is from the current time (represent the time in seconds, use `time` to get the current time, subtract). You know the GMT offset of your current location (and your server knows it, `date` can give it to you). Subtract again and you know the GMT offset of the time. Now you just need a map of GMT offsets to time zones, which you can easily pull out of Wikipedia; there will be multiple time zone names for most offsets.

Comment: +1 Generally, you're right... but I disagree about that "easily pull out of Wikipedia" part. Yes, you can easily find timezone offset but finding location is not that easy task. Try it by yourself ;)

Comment: But this wouldn't account for daylight saving time though would it? Since GMT offsets vary by the time of year.